# Spark Streaming HDFS

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

When using spark streaming and the built in HDFS support, I have encountered the follwing inconvenience:

**dStream.saveAsTextFiles** produces many subdirectories in HDFS.  **rdd.saveAsTextFile** also creates subdirectories for each set of parts.

I am looking for a method which puts all of the parts in the same path:

**myHdfsPath/Prefix_time-part0XXX**

instead of

**myHdfsPath/Prefix_time/part0XXX**

That way I can later iterate over these files more easily by scanning a single HDFS directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can process the result of the saveAsTextFile and merge the files generated:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._

def saveAsTextFileAndMerge[T](hdfsServer: String, fileName: String, rdd: RDD[T]) = {
    val sourceFile = hdfsServer + "/tmp/" 
    rdd.saveAsTextFile(sourceFile)
    val dstPath = hdfsServer + "/final/" 
    merge(sourceFile, dstPath, fileName)
  }

  def merge(srcPath: String, dstPath: String, fileName: String): Unit = {
    val hadoopConfig = new Configuration()
    val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConfig)
    val destinationPath = new Path(dstPath)
    if (!hdfs.exists(destinationPath)) {
      hdfs.mkdirs(destinationPath)
    }
    FileUtil.copyMerge(hdfs, new Path(srcPath), hdfs, new Path(dstPath + "/" + fileName), false, hadoopConfig, null)
  }
```

Another way is to collect the rdd and call HDFS Java API to write a single file. But that means that your rdd is small enough to be collected and as you know, collect the rdd is inefficient.

I hope this can help.

Comment: I don't need the part files to be merged. Having multiple files in the same dir is ok. I do want them in the *same* dir though. So that I can process them more easily

Comment: Sorry I've misunderstood the question. Have you tried the collect?.
That said, if you don't want to do the collect, I think you can use the same code but FileIUtil.copy (to a destiny fixed) instead FileUtil.copyMerge. There is no way to use saveAsTextFile the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a `repartition(1)` on your RDD before calling the write command.

Now if you are using Spark Streaming, you first have to `collect()` all the data you want to write, then repartition, then write it.